# Custom UISplitViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I want the effect of a UISplitViewController however I am not using the split view template.

Is it relatively easy to achieve without the template? And with using normal UIViewController?

What I want it a customary sized and positioned UITableView which then has a customary sized detail view which then of course goes into a popover and detail view when portrait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it without Interface Builder, you would create a UIViewController class. In the viewDidLoad method of that class, create a UIView or a UITableView with the frame origin where you want it and a size that you want. (Release it in the viewDidUnload method.) Then set the UIViewController's self.view to point to this new view.

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:...];    // edit - added in response to your question
```

If you created a UIView, then you will want to put your UITableView inside this new view. (This approach lets you add more items to the container UIView if you need to.)

Make sure your UIViewController adheres to the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols. Add the delegate and datasource methods and you should be good to go.

This new view can cover other views, or you can size the other views to fit beside it. You only need to set there frames according to what you want to do with them.

There are some limitations if you use a UITableViewController, so a lot of people recommend using a UIViewController instead. like I described above. You can google for more info on that topic.

Comment: "Then set the UIViewController's self.view to point to this new view." Point to the new view in what way? Im fairly sure I understand what you have said otherwise, so I just follow the code seen in the template with the additionally customisation which you mentioned and Im there, right?

Comment: See my edit in my original response. This should help. If you use IB, I belive this is automatically done for you, if you hook everything up right. I prefer to right the code myself, so I can see all the hooks in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Just great a new temporary Xcode-project from that template and judge yourself, if it is complicated for you, to adept your (real) code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it quite easily. Just use delegates to pass messages between the left and the right side views (root and detail). For instance the didSelectRowAtIndexPath tableView method could be used along with delegation to pass a message to the right sided detail view. Tap a cell on the left table, show its text as a Label on the right side. Its just a simple example. And yes you can handle the rotations and send left side view into a UIPopoverController as well, thus giving the detail view full screen real estate in Portrait orientation.

Also try [MGSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/) . It gives you a lot of other customization options on a split view controller.