# Manually creating a Split View layout without using UISplitViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I'm diving into iOS development and I'm trying to create an iPad app that uses the split view layout, without using the UISplitViewController. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666448/custom-uisplitviewcontroller) already posted, but it's too vague to help me with my current level of iOS experience.

In short, I have a UIViewController class named MySplitViewController that contains two children view controllers, one for the master view and one for the detail view.  I'm trying to implement this in a way that when I push an instance of MySplitViewController onto the nav stack, I get a table view (master) on the left and a detail view on the left.  However, when I run my code, the entire split view is filled with the table view.  How can I manually create a Split View layout?  Here are my three view controller classes, they're very simple...

**MySplitViewController.m**

```
#import "MySplitViewController.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MYSplitViewController (){}

@property (nonatomic, strong) MasterViewController *masterViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) DetailViewController *detailViewController;

@end

@implementation MySplitViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
      self.masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
      self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004);
    [self.view addSubview:self.masterViewController.view];
    [self.masterViewController viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:self.detailViewController.view];
    [self.detailViewController viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

**MasterViewController.m**

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 1004) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    table.dataSource = self;
    table.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:table];
}

@end
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *uiview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 668, 1004)];
    [self.view addSubview:uiview];
}

@end
```

What am I not understanding?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

P.S. It's worth noting why I'm not using the UISplitViewController.  My app is currently designed so that the root view is not split view.  The root view of my app will cause a split view to be pushed on to the nav stack.  The problem with this is that the UISplitViewController is designed to be the root view of an app and Apple's docs specifically say that if you use a UISplitViewController that it needs to be the root view.  Therefor, I'm implementing my own split view and manually managing the views.

Comment: I understand better your other question now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe thinking about showing your root view in a different way could help you. e.g like this: using a `UISplitViewController` as root view and present a modal view on top of it with your current root view. So you use your current root view and the `UISplitViewController`.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, thank you Pfitz! What about the transition animation tho? If I present my current root view as a modal view, can I animate the transition to the split view (actual root view) with an animation that looks like the split view is being pushed onto the stack?

Comment: haven't used this technique with non standard animations but I think it is possible via the `modalTransitionStyle` property of the view controller

Answer (score 1):

you might wanna try MGSplitViewController which is also based on UIViewController.. and allows push..[MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController)

Comment: Thanks AppleDelegate!  The price ($199) is a bit out of my range, however, and my app requires a non-attribution license.  Any tips on what I'm doing wrong in my current approach?